# Why do [Ctrl]+[letter] shortcuts suddenly not work anymore in KeePass 2.x under Linux Mint, while most other programs are fine?

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, mono

I haven't updated KeyPass 2.x (I'm still on 2.32), so what could have broken this program on Linux Mint 18.1 x64?

It used to be that normal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+[letter] shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to open URL in browser, etc. worked fine on this system.  Now none of them do.  I have to right-click and use context menu options.  This persists after a restart.  Unfortunately I'm not sure what updated that might have broken this.

It seems the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> part is just being ignored entirely: In any text box within KeyPass where I try to paste with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+V, it instead types the letter `v` into the box.

Aside from KeyPass, everywhere else in the system my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key works just fine for copy/paste/undo/select all/etc.  The only exception is that I also recently experienced this in pgAdminIII, but restarting the program (or perhaps my whole computer--not sure which it was) fixed it, because the problem did not persist after that.  KeyPass remains broken between cold boots.

What components are at play here?  How can I diagnose such a problem?

KeePass 2.x seems to be based on Mono, but I don't have `mono-complete` installed--I installed from the repo mentioned at https://sourceforge.net/p/keepass/discussion/329220/thread/17d1bd26/#4a47/2783 (IIRC--it was months ago now, and it's been working since then until somewhat recently.  But I did seem to have that repo already there when I tried to add it again just now, so unless it didn't work and I installed some other way without cleaning up the repo, that's the version I have.  From the rest of that thread I gather that the version I have has whatever it needs from Mono already compiled in?)

---

For lack of other ideas, after all the above, I upgraded to KeePass 2.36.  It still has this behaviour.

Also it doesn't matter if I use left or right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, or even both at the same time.

Comment: I am also facing this issue in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just switched to KeePassXC 2.2.0 (oldstable) and it works fine in the above regard, and was able to open existing database files from KeePass2.

This doesn't really answer the question as to what caused the above, but it's a useful solution, at least.